# CICS web service requestor GET CONTAINER returns neither data nor error

Tags: web-services, cics

I am developing a CICS web service requestor application to consume a distributed web service.
I used the web services assistant DFHWS2LS to transform the wsdl to copybooks successfully.

I have no problem issuing the PUT CONTAINER and INVOKE SERVICE api commands, but when I issue GET CONTAINER I am not receiving any containers or data. No response codes or error messages, but no data. Any ideas on how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen `RESP` be `DFHRESP(NORMAL)` and `RESP2` be zero and have nothing returned by the server.

Verify the WSDL specifies that something is, in fact, returned by the web service.

Check the `RESP` and `RESP2` values returned by the `INVOKE SERVICE` API.  You don't mention these explicitly, and I presume the former is `DFHRESP(NORMAL)` and the latter is 0, but you might have coded `NOHANDLE` so I thought I'd ask.

Take a look in the TD queue mapped to `CSSL` (the default is the `MSGUSR DD`) for your CICS region.  This is where CICS logs messages when it runs into an error while processing your SOAP request.  Look for messages prefixed `DFHPI`.

Try pinging the endpoint from a TSO session running on the same LPAR as your CICS region, it's possible you're being stopped by a firewall.

In your comment you indicate the requestor is "seeing whitespace on the `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope tag>`".  This isn't something under your direct control.  The CICS "plumbing" code takes care of formatting the SOAP message.  You may want to ask your CICS Systems Programmer to look for APARs related to the problem and install any associated PTFs.

You could verify the requestor's claim by using the transport handler in Appendix A.3 of [this redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247206.html?Open).  You'll have to modify your pipeline configuration file to execute the handler.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Yes, I am checking the response and response2 codes on the PUT CONTAINER and INVOKE SERVICE, all are zero.

Comment: According to the vendor, they are seeing whitespace on the <SOAP-ENV:Envelope tag>, and claim that is why they are unable to format the response correctly. Ever heard of this before? If so, how can I get the soap envelope to format with any whitespaces? Thanks, Namhcir

Comment: Thanks for the tip. CICS is the requestor, not provider. After PUT CONTAINER and INVOKE SERVICE (both 0 for resp/resp2) I browsed the containers on the channel. A dozen containers existed on the channel, including DFHFUNCTION, DFHRESPONSE, DFHWS-BODY, DFHWS-OPERATION, DFHWS-WEBSERVICE, and DFHWS-DATA. The last container, DFHWS-DATA was empty; DFHWS-BODY also contained an empty response in the SOAP-ENV:Body tag. Other containers had expected values. Seems the service provider is not providing a response. Vendor still faults whitespace on SOAP-ENV:Envelope tag; our sysprog is researching it.